# Acroread Firefox plugin Ubuntu 12.04 issues

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, every time I try to open a PDF through Firefox (which I like to do quite often as I read a lot of PDF documents and downloading each then deleting is tiresome) I get the error message:

> Could not launch Adobe Reader 9.5.1. Please make sure it exists in PATH variable in the environment. If the problem persists, please reinstall the application.

If I launch Firefox from the terminal the message it gives when attempting to open a PDF is:

```
(firefox:5989): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(firefox:5989): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_set_back_pixmap: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
/usr/bin/acroread: 23: exec: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

---

I should mention loading a PDF from say the Desktop is fine.  I only get error when loading a PDF via the browser.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

```
ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread | grep not 

libBIB.so => not found
libBIBUtils.so => not found
libACE.so => not found
libAGM.so => not found
libCoolType.so => not found
libAXE8SharedExpat.so => not found
libJP2K.so => not found
libAdobeXMP.so => not found
libicuuc.so.36 => not found
libResAccess.so => not found
```

Comment: Output of `ls -l /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread`?

Comment: Output is:-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24525572 Mar 28 11:47 /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously caused by apparmor.

All you need is add a line to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` and reload the rules.

e.g inside the brackets,

```
  # Allow execution of adobe reader
  /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread ixr,
```

I don't have a 32bit machine, those were not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try fixing permissions, since this looks like a lack of exec-permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread
```

This resets the file's permissions to be read and executed by world and group, and read, written, and executed by owner. Now, we'll set the owner to `root`, for good measure:

```
sudo chown root: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I entered both of these, restarted firefox and attempted to open a PDF but still got the same errors as in my OP unfortunately.

Comment: @fpghost Can you try reinstalling acroread? I hope there's no file corruption, especially bad ELF headers...

Comment: @fpghost Also, can you try executing `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread` directly?

Comment: I removed (via SoftwareCentre) acroread then installed it again. I didn't reinstall the firefox plugin itself (as I don't know how-there is a 'disable' option but not remove; also in about:config I can't see it). No luck still. Executing the command you mention gives an error too: "/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libBIB.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: OK. I'm a little unsure of what to do next. I'm very sorry.

Comment: thanks anyway. I'm not sure either, but this thread looks possibly relevant to the last error: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-899492-start-0.html

Comment: Also: ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread | grep not 
 libBIB.so => not found
 libBIBUtils.so => not found
 libACE.so => not found
 libAGM.so => not found
 libCoolType.so => not found
 libAXE8SharedExpat.so => not found
 libJP2K.so => not found
 libAdobeXMP.so => not found
 libicuuc.so.36 => not found
 libResAccess.so => not found

Comment: If you're on 64-bit, try installing `ia32-libs` using `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`.